# Understanding OpenCV's drawing calls: Are those lines of code irrelevant?

Tags: python, opencv

Source: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

In that tutorial the lines of code:

```
cv.rectangle(frame, (10, 2), (100,20), (255,255,255), -1)
cv.putText(frame, str(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)), (15, 15),
           cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5 , (0,0,0))
```

are used. However, as far as I understand it, one would need to save their return value onto the frame, to have any change at all since they are not "in place":

```
frame = cv.rectangle(frame, (10, 2), (100,20), (255,255,255), -1)
frame = cv.putText(frame, str(capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)), (15, 15),
           cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5 , (0,0,0))
```

But even then I can't really see a difference in the result.

Am I missing something?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you misunderstood.

Those calls work *on* the array object you passed into them. They **modify** the image array.

There is *absolutely no reason* to catch the return value because it **is** the **same** array object you passed in. Not just equal, but the same, **identical**. A reference to one and the same object. **Do not** catch the return value.

If you don't see something, there's a reason for it, but this is not the reason. You did not provide enough code to reproduce any issue you might have.

Comment: I was looking at the foreground mask, but only the regular frame is altered. Your explanation solved that mystery for me.